# Same controller two components lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is it possible to have the same apex controller being used by two different aura components? I'm trying to do that but the the component controller is getting an error response from the apex controller. This is my code:

**Component:**

```
        <div class="{!'slds-box slds-theme–alert-texture slds-theme–' + v.type}">
             <lightning:icon iconName="{! 'utility:'+ v.type }" size="medium"
                             alternativeText="{!v.type}" Class="iconContainer"/>&nbsp;
        <span class="slds-text-body–regular">
             <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.message}"/>
        </span>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="slds-p-around--medium">
            <div class="slds-float--right">
                <lightning:button label="Close" 
                                  class="slds-button slds-button_brand"
                                  variant="brand"
                                  onclick="{!c.closeBtn}"/>
             </div>
         </div>
```

**Component JS Controller**

```
({
handleRecordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.setCall");
    console.log("Test1");
     //set the parameters
     action.setParams({
         nif: component.get("v.simpleLead").NIF__c,
         country: component.get("v.simpleLead").Country
     })
     console.log("Test2 " + component.get("v.simpleLead").Country);
     action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS"){
            console.log("Success");  
            if(response.getReturnValue()==="Success"){
                component.set("v.type", "success" );
                component.set("v.message", response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (response.getReturnValue()!="Success"){
                component.set("v.type", "error" );
                component.set("v.message", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            }

        else if (state === "ERROR") {
        console.log("Error");
            component.set("v.type", "error" );
            var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                  if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                     component.set("v.message",errors[0].message );//Fetching Custom Message.
                     }
                  }
         }
         else {
              component.set("v.message", 'Request Failed!' );
         }
    });
    //Send action off to be executed
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

},

closeBtn : function(component, event, helper) {
    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
    dismissActionPanel.fire();
}
}
})
```

**Apex controller**

```
public with sharing class Ctrl_CallInformaDB {
@AuraEnabled
public static string setCall(String nif, String country){

    string errorCode = InformaDB_API.CreditInfoProviderOrquestrator(nif,country);
    string returnMessage;
    List<Translate_Metadata__mdt> messages=[SELECT Value_EN__c FROM Translate_Metadata__mdt WHERE label = : errorCode];
    for(Translate_Metadata__mdt s : messages){
       System.debug('message ' + s.Value_EN__c);
       returnMessage = s.Value_EN__c;
       }

    return returnMessage;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but we would need to see a specific failing example to help you.

Comment: I posted my code that is failing with an response.getState = Error.

Comment: Can you check if you are passing the parameters correctly?

Comment: I did that and both parameters are passing the value correctly.

Comment: Did you check debug log from developer console?

Comment: No, I checked  the Javascript console in chrome.

Comment: I ckecked it now and I'm reveiving the message : Illegal arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the nif field set to decimal, and the method was expecting a string. So one of the parameters was passing a decimal to the apex controller while this one was expecting a string, thus trowing an illegal argument error. Thank you for the help!